# Run Custom C# Code In A "Web Site" From An IIS "Application"

Tags: c#, iis-6

I have a tough question here and I would like to tap the wisdom of the masses to ensure that I am approaching this issue in the most efficient way possible.

Goal: Move 78 web applications (all configured to be an IIS application under a root website) from a Windows Server 2003 box to a 2012 box with as little coding as possible. The 2012 box has a different subdomain "xxx2.blah.com" and the 03 server is mapped to a "xxx.blah.com" server. In short, the user bookmarks won't work once we migrate so we want to write a redirection utility to assist getting the users to the new xxx2.blach.com location without them noticing.

Current State:It is important to note that each application under the root website in IIS6 is configured to run under its own, and sometimes shared, app pools. Some of the applications have querystring values appended to the end of the .NET request that we want to retain because it affects the UI and other business logic already coded.

We were thinking of removing the files within each application to force IIS to return a 404. Once the 404 occurs, we were wanting to run our custom utility to lookup what the equivalent URL is. Since the 404 is an "error" by all intents and purposes, we were thinking that we could "handle" the error like this ([ASP.NET 2.0 : Best Practice for writing Error Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227632/asp-net-2-0-best-practice-for-writing-error-page))

Is it possible to write that code once, add the logic to the global.asax file in the root website, and then somehow instruct each web application under that root site to execute the code in the parent site? I know they each run under their own app pool and that may mean that we cannot pass execution off onto another application easily but I could be wrong. In addition, we are hoping to not have to copy/paste code 78 times. Any general "best practices" or advice would be greatly appreciated. Also, adjusting it on the network is not an option as the old xxx.blah.com is on a completely different network than the new xxx2.blah.com network.

Comment: Would need to see your network topology but I highly doubt it is not an option. I would explore using redirects at the network level before even considering changing one line of application code.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted. I was hoping for a best practices type of approach and not actual source code. If I left out an important part of the question or if it didn't have enough meat on the bones to be generally understood, please ask a clarifying question for the sake of the other readers. But like I said, thank you all for your time and wisdom.

Comment: Why don't you just use an http redirect? https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/6b855a7a-0884-4508-ba95-079f38c77017.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: The issue with the http redirect (assuming you meant in the web.config file  custom errors section) is that I don't get the full path or the query string values like we need. For instance if "xxx.blah.com/mysite?id=4" was requested, I only get the "/mysite" value accessible to me. Like this "xxx2.blah.com/ServerMigrationURLMapper/URLMapper.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/mysite".

Using the http redirect was my first option and I am finding it difficult to obtain the full URI after the redirect.

Comment: @Solo812 I haven't used IIS6 for a while - but you should be able to configure the redirect via the IIS6 dialog for the site - this might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480530/301-redirect-with-querystring-iis6

Comment: Thank you Carl. I will investigate this to see what we have. The SO post you linked me to had a similar issue but their solution wasn't ideal as I can really enter an exact URL as the query string values change between almost every request. But, maybe I could just change the execution path of the application to use one single new webapp with all of the new logic in it. That may work!

Comment: @Solo812, if you follow the link in the SO answer, you can use $S$Q which will automatically append the requested subdirectory and querystring to the redirect. Using your example - if you set your redirect to xxx2.blah.com$S$Q then xxx.blah.com/mysite?id=4 would be redirected to xxx2.blah.com/mysite?id=4 - where "/mysite" replaces $S and "?id=4" replaces $Q

Answer (score 0):

@Carl

Thank you very much. I initially missed that those variables were available to me for this purpose! The final solution for me was to set the "Redirect To" textbox to "http://xxx2.blah.com$V?UpdateNote=true&$P". This enables the redirection to occur with both the path and querystring name/value pairs in tact and also allowed me to append my own value so that the application could detect it and display a "This page has moved" message to the user.

Thank you Carl! You da man.